# Acrhimesh Texture Problem

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, add-on, archimesh-add-on

I am struck with a very annoying problem, I have created a Cube and fixed a texture on the cube using UV Map. Everything is fine, But When i add archimesh, the texture is removed, and when i add any primitive object like plane, etc. then texture remains.

Does anyone have idea, whats going on with Archimesh.. I searched google, youtube for tutorial or the solution, but nothing found about texturing an archimesh. Please help me how to solve it..

Here is the Video - Whats going on - `http://tinypic.com/r/2s91zb7/9`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug *(when stuff is added)* or by design but this addon seems to expect Cycles as the default engine as the new objects get created with a cycles mat (perhaps ask on the github repo?). Notice the engine switches when you add a new archimesh object. The texture isn't disappearing, the engine just changes and Blender Internal and Cycles materials can't be used simultaneously or interchangeably .

Simply switch back the engine, delete the cycles material from the archimesh and add a new material and texture that.

Comment: ye, Great !!! When i changed from Cycle to Blender Render, its done a trick.. I really appreciated it.. Thanks